# mysql query to get the min values according to the latesttime stamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I have try to find a solution for a query to get the minvalues along with latest time stamp.

I have following tables

Table1

```
sno user_id   name subject  rank         Timestamp
 1    10      SS   maths1  1     2014-12-05 17:24:33 
 2    10      SS   maths2  2     2014-12-05 17:24:33
 3    10      PH   phy1    3     2014-12-05 17:24:33
 4    10      PH   phy2    4     2014-12-05 17:24:33
 5    10      SS   maths1  2     2014-12-04 17:24:33 
 6    10      SS   maths2  1     2014-12-04 17:24:33
 7    10      PH   phy1    3     2014-12-04 17:24:33
 8    10      PH   phy2    4     2014-12-04 17:24:33
```

Tabe12

```
sno  name  Status
1     SS    Active
2     PH    ACtive
3     So    Inactive
```

So I am trying to get the following result

```
 sno userid   name   subject  rank         timpestamp
     1    10      SS   maths1  1     2014-12-05 17:24:33 
     2    10      PH   phy1    3     2014-12-05 17:24:33
```

So far I tried this query I am able to get the latest time and least rank values for subjects with Distinct name.
but they are not connected to each other means I getting the latesttime stamp and least value from some other row. Please help me How to solve it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(T1.`name`), 
       T1.`user_id`,
       T1.`subject`, 
       MAX(T1.`Timestamp`) as latest_Timestamp, 
       MIN(T1.`rank `) as rank   
FROM Table1  T1,Table2 T2  
where T1.`user_id`='10' 
AND  T2.`status` = 'Active' 
AND T1.`name` = T2.`name`  
GROUP BY T1.`exercise_id`
ORDER BY T1.`quality_id`, T1.`Timestamp` ASC
```

Comment: It appears to me you want each users highest rank with most current timestamp, otherwise rank 2 should be displayed as would rank 4.  is this correct?

Comment: ? But they're all active, so don't bother with t2

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases work well on sets. So think of the data in different sets

- You need a set that combines t1 and t2
- You need a subset of t1 that only consists of the min rank and max timestamp for each user_Id and name.

So T1 and T2 are joined generating the universe of data and columns you need.  We then join to the  subquery contianing the subset to filter out the non max timestamp and non-min rank you want.

```
SELECT T1values.name, 
       T1values.user_id,
       T1values.subject, 
       T1values.rank,
       T1values.timestamp
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN table1 t1Values
  ON t1values.sno = t2.sno
 and t2.status='Active'
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_Id, name max(timestamp) maxTime, min(rank) Mrank 
            FROM Table1 
            GROUP BY user_Id, Name) T1
 ON t1.name = T1values.name
and t1.user_Id = t1values.user_ID
and t1.maxTime = T1Values.timestamp
and t1.rank = T1values.mrank
WHERE T1values.user_id='10' 
ORDER BY T1values.quality_id, T1values.Timestamp ASC
```

Comment: Hi xQbert I tried your query but it is not working in all aspects.